# How to initialize structure in main function

Tags: c, struct, initialization, pgm

I am trying to write simple pgm file reading C program. I had to create simple structure:

```
typedef struct pgmImage {
   int R; //rows
   int C; //collumns
   int G; //grey scale
   int **pix;  // array of pixels
}Image;
```

Now i have to initialize empty Image structure.I need one to set all variables based on *.pgm file in other function.
All the time i am getting "unable to read memory" and 'unitialized local variable x used'.  I have tried to simply do :

> Image *x=0;

but program crashes when read function try to set R,C,G values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a pointer to Image you have to initialize  like this.

```
Image *x = NULL;
```

Accessing the image (x) camps like this :

```
x-> C = 0;
x-> ...
x->pix = NULL;
```

But first you need to allocate memory to your image.

```
x = (Image*) malloc(sizeof(Image));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Image x = {0}
```

it s a static memory allocation of image element `x`

or

```
Image *x = calloc(1,(sizeof(Image));
```

it s a dynamic memory allocation of image and `x` is a pointer to the allocated memory

the `calloc` will allocate emory and initiate all memory to 0, so the pointer in the structure will be initiated systematically to NULL

Comment: This utilisation of `calloc` with null pointers is not portable.

Comment: this because **pix is a double pointer ? this what you mean ?

Comment: `calloc` sets all bit to zero, but `NULL` does not have necessarily such representation. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5857706/1126268

Comment: @Kirilenko I checked some stdlib.h and the NULL macro is defined as 0 please check the following links http://www.mers.byu.edu/docs/standardC/stdlib.html  http://trac.assembla.com/chdk/browser/trunk/include/stdlib.h?order=name

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a pointer, you have to allocate enough memory to hold a structure. However, you are trying to dereference a null pointer: this leads to undefined behavior.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
Image *x = malloc(sizeof *x);
```

And then you can initialize the members. NB: Use `calloc` here is non-portable, because a null-pointer is not guaranteed to have a memory representation all-bits-zero.

Anyway, it seems that you don't need to use a pointer here.

```
#include <stddef.h>
Image x = { 0, 0, 0, NULL };
```

Comment: If you do Image * x = malloc(sizeof *x); you will get the following error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'Image*'

Comment: Read my answer. It's `Image *x`.